# How to create an array of sounds that play randomly with more than one button?

Tags: xcode5

I'm looking for a way to play sounds randomly with 10 buttons for example and each button sticks to the sound it gets randomly after every run. Is that possible? because the code I have below kind of does that but keeps giving random sounds every time I press the buttons. I hope someone can help me make the randomization occur once at the beginning of the app so that each button has its own sound until I quit the app and so on.

```
int arrayRows =[self.soundList count];
int index = (arc4random() % arrayRows);

NSString *sound_List = [self.soundList objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *randomMP3File = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound_List ofType:@"mp3"];                           
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:randomMP3File] error:NULL];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add 10 buttons to your view and set unique tag value to each button from 0 -> 9
- Create array of sound files when app is started, files every time in random order
- If button with tag 1 is pressed, play sound file at array index 1 and so on...

Comment: Thank you juniperi for your answer which seems logical. So yeah I set the tags via the attributes inspector and created an array of sound files in the viewDidLoad and the arc4Random code so I should then do something like this:


 - (void) buttonAction:(id)sender { 

switch (((UIButton *)sender).tag) { 

case 1: // play sound at index 0 

break;


 case 2: // play sound at index 1


 break;

 ....... 

default: 

break;

 }

 } 

Is this right? and what should I write inside each case?